# How to sort a number with thousands separator

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, datatables, string-formatting

I have tried to sort the number with [jQuery Datatables plug-in](http://datatables.net/) but is not working with C# string number formats.

I have tried:

```
decimal value= 12345678.00
value..ToString("#,##.00");
value.ToString("##,##.##");
value.ToString("0,0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

but no luck because of the comma. If there is no comma is works fine or all the numbers with same count also working i.e.

> 01,121,372.01
>
> 02,002,009.22
>
> 11,222,222,33

If it is as below then it is not working

> 1,111,111.11
>
> 222,191.00
>
> 32,222.00

Comment: Then try to turn the string into a number. C# doesn't have any special rules for sorting with numbers in a string, it just sorts it based on alpha-numeric characters. The only way you can get accurate sorting is if you store it as a number truly within the datatable then sort on it and display the string value after sort.

Comment: Is it JQuery Datatable?

Comment: yes is it is JQuery Datatable

Answer (score 1):

I have done like this to overcome to this issue.

```
"aoColumnDefs": [ {
                    "aTargets": [3,4,6],
                    "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                        var $currencyCell = $(nTd);
                        var commaValue = $currencyCell.text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
                        $currencyCell.text(commaValue);
                    }
                }]
```

Answer (score 0):

**For DataTables 1.10**

DataTables 1.10+ has formatted number detection and sorting abilities built- in, there is no extra coding needed.

Alternatively you can set [columns.type](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type) to `num-fmt` to force specific data type.

See the example below for demonstration.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable();

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

  </head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>111,111.11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>222,191.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>32,222.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**For DataTables 1.9**

For older DataTables 1.9 you can use [Formatted numbers](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/formatted-numbers) sorting plug-in.

You just need to include this JS file: //cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/sorting/formatted-numbers.js and use the code below to set data type to formatted number.

```
$('#example').dataTable({
   columnDefs: [
     { type: 'formatted-num', targets: 0 }
   ]
});
```

Comment: @Juan, there is a confusion I believe. The question is about jQuery DataTables plug-in as OP noted in the comments, not .NET class `DataTable`. Although the formatting problem could be solved on the server-side as well with C#, there are downsides since the number would still need to be formatted on the client-side.